# How to run Meteor insert within a Fiber

Tags: javascript, meteor, ethereum

Note:  there are many questions on this topic, but I'm not able to get my code (due to syntax issues, etc.) into the right format.  So this is a question about my specific instance.

I have some code in init.js under the "lib" folder to take an event from the web3/ethereum package and store it in a collection.  Note that the question is purely a Meteor question though.  I've included the contextual information about web3/ethereum because it is probably a similar issue encountered by other people working with storing web3/ethereum events in a Meteor collection.

```
var events = contract_instance.allEvents([]);

events.watch(function(error, event){
  if (!error)
    console.log(event.args);

var event_object_value1 = event.args.value1;
//everything up to this point works fine.  event_object is in a json format.

//inserting the value into a collection on the server side like this is what causes the error.
collection.insert({"key": value1});
});
```

The last line produces the `Meteor code must always run within a Fiber.`error.  Normally, I would insert using a Meteor Method, but I suspect I would get the same error when actually doing the insert.

There are quite a few questions on this error on stackoverflow, but I haven't really been able to get my code within a fiber correctly.  I've tried to follow this example here, but I think it's just way to above my understanding of Meteor:
https://meteorhacks.com/fibers-eventloop-and-meteor/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace

```
events.watch(function(error, event) {
  ...
});
```

with

```
events.watch(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(error, event) {
  ...
}));
```

`Meteor.bindEnvironment` ensures that the wrapped function runs within a fiber.